# Open a .dat file regardless of name in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

Is there a way in c to read in a .dat file regardless of the name for example say I have a file a.dat and then later I change it to b.dat. Is there a way to make it so that this file will be read in anyway. For example would:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(".dat", "r");
```

read in either of these files and if not what is the way to do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if both `b.dat` and `c.dat` exist? What if you rename it into a totally different directory or file system?

Comment: You can implement file lookup using `readdir()` and decide what to do with each found file

Comment: When you rename it you could make a symbolic link.

Comment: fopen takes an implicit file name or path + file name. You will have to manage multiple files outside of this function (i.e. in program logic).

Comment: If you need to only read this file, you can make a copy somewhere else (in TEMP directory) and then open it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work and check file extension :

```
  struct dirent *dent;
  DIR           *dir;

  dir = opendir(directory);
  if (dir != NULL)
    {
      while ((dent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if ((dent->d_type == DT_DIR) && (check_file_extension(dent->d_name, ".dat") == 0))
                do_something_with_your_file(dent->d_name);
        }
       closedir(dir);
    }
```